# CAD files like dxf/dwg to WMS

Tags: arcgis, autocad, wms, dxf, dwg

I have a really complicated and complex CAD file that ArcGIS can't show me correctly, is there any service that loads the dwg or dxf file and gives it to me in map or raster form? Something like WMS?

I'm a surveyor, who uses ArcGIS software and I'm trying to load a dxf file, but because the file is complex and complicated it takes a long time to load and it doesn't display it properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nice solution is to convert the DXF or DWG file into WMS layer that ArcGIS or any other GIS client can load.
Because WMS is raster based, then it is shown "as is" and doesn't rely on the GIS client to interpret the content of the file, and also, when many feature exist in the same area so the drawing is "dense" then WMS will perform way better because the process of rendering was already done in advance.

Check out this:
https://www.web-map-service.com/